# Rcpp cannot find make, but it is in my PATH

Tags: r, rcpp

I am doing Hadley Wickhams [basic Rcpp Tutorial](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Rcpp), the first line of code gets me stumped:

```
> library(Rcpp)
> cppFunction('
+   int add(int x, int y, int z) {
+             int sum = x + y + z;
+             return sum;
+             }'
+ )
g++ -m64 -I"C:/R/R-30~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/Users/Michael/R/win-library/Rcpp/include"  -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c file1dc033292fcb.cpp -o file1dc033292fcb.o make: sh.exe: Command not found make: *** [file1dc033292fcb.o] Error 127 
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, showOutput = showOutput,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

Both `make` and `sh.exe` are in my path, I can use them from Command Prompt. I can even call `sh` from command prompt and use `make` inside that sub-process. I'm using Windows 7, 64-bit.

My Path:

```
C:\cygwin\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin;C:\R\R-3.0.1\bin;C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin64;C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\i686-w64-mingw32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64;C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin
```

I don't have any spaces in Path variable it should need to look for.

Comment: FYI if you do this from rstudio, it will make sure the path is set correctly, or warn you otherwise.

Comment: Make sure that the following two entries come up in your path first: `C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin`, and make sure you have a version of Rtools installed that's compatible with your current version of R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use Cygwin (as much as we all like `bash`) for R builds or if you must, ensure that that `Rtools` path entries come first.

As you cannot build R on Windows without Rtools (which is MinGW-based) I often complement it with MSys.

Comment: seems to have changed something, now it says: `sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in make`, I googled it and it seems that this should be fixed by putting C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin at the front of the path, however I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: The R Installation and Administration manual has these words of wisdom in Appendix D:  _This appendix contains a lot of prescriptive comments. They are here as a result of bitter experience. Please do not report problems to the R mailing lists unless you have followed all the prescriptions._   You *really* need to follow the prescriptions.

Comment: No that is not correct. R itself can (should ?) be the standard binary.  Also note that there are numerous tutorials on the Web helping with this.

Comment: This answer lead me to the correct one, which is to have Rtools in the front of the *system path* not just user path. As a result, not only did I have Cygwin in front, but also a Haskell 32-bit g++.

Comment: Good to know you have it working. Now re-read the first line I wrote in my answer :)